# Reading a number from Firebase Firestore database and using in a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can read a number from the database perfectly fine into a paragraph text in html but I want to use this same number in a function to return a number but when I try to subtract the number in the database from a different number inputted into a textbox I get 'NaN'

Number coming from the firestore database

```
db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
  var dafcoin = `
  <div>${doc.data().DAFcoins}</div>
`;
DAFcoins.innerHTML = dafcoin;
});
```

The function inside a click event (y is the number coming from the database, x is the number coming from the input box)

```
function sendCoins(){
const sendcoinsForm = document.querySelector('#sendcoins-form');
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("newbalance").value);
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("sendcoins-hours").value);
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = x;
var youruid = document.getElementById("your-uid").value;

var z = myFunction(y, x);
function myFunction(a, b){
    return a - b;
}
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z;

db.collection("users").doc(youruid).update({
"DAFcoins": z
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    window.alert("Balance updated! You have successfully sent coins to " + sentuid);
    sendcoinsForm.reset();
});

}
```

Comment: after .get() put .then(res=>{logic to display res.data()})

Comment: That didn't work for me if I was doing it correctly